# styling segmented button group programmatically

Tags: android, button

I have made a custom segmented button group utilizing (https://github.com/ceryle/SegmentedButton?utm_source=android-arsenal.com&utm_medium=referral&utm_campaign=4445)

I am able to adjust all the settings correctly except borders and dividers.

```
    rg.setSelectorColor(Color.rgb(255,153,0));
    rg.setTextColorOnSelection(Color.WHITE);
    rg.setTextColorOnSelection(true);
    rg.setSelectorAnimationDuration(100);

    rg.setDivider(true);
    rg.setDividerSize(3);
    rg.setDividerRadius(26);
    rg.setDividerPadding(26);
    rg.setDividerColor(Color.BLACK);
```

Ie. the top half of my code works, but the bottom half does not make the expected divider (as seen on the top of the below image link, one that I hard-coded in xml).

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d5lhu.png)